# Pages Keeps Refreshing While Using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im creating a modal box that includes a form. The form will then return the input once submitted using ajax and php and the modal box should then disappear. The problem is though the result shows for a few seconds before the box disappears and the page refreshes.

```
<button class="toggleModal">trigger iModal</button>

<div class="modal">

<header>
  <h2>Other Symptoms</h2>
  <i  class="fa fa-times close toggleModal"></i>
</header>

<section>     
   <form class="js-ajax-php-json" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <textarea name="textareathebeast"  row="4" cols="40" placeholder="some text"></textarea><br>
    <input class="modalSubmit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
</section>

</div>

<div class="the-return">
  [HTML is replaced when successful.]
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

>

```
$(function(){  

$('.toggleModal').on('click', function (e) {

     $('.modal').toggleClass('active');

});

$(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(){
var data = {
  "action": "test"
};
data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "response.php",
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    $(".the-return").html(
      "Text Message: " + data["textareathebeast"]
    );
  }
});
return true;    
});

});
</script>
```

<

```
<?php
  if (is_ajax()) {
    if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
      $action = $_POST["action"];
      switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
        case "test": test(); break;
     }
  }
}

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {
   return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function test(){
  $return = $_POST;

//Do what you need to do with the info. The following are some examples.
//if ($return["favorite_beverage"] == ""){
//  $return["favorite_beverage"] = "Coke";
//}
//$return["favorite_restaurant"] = "McDonald's";

$return["json"] = json_encode($return);
echo json_encode($return);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitting a form implies lots of default behavior, such as reloading the current page with the results of the submission (even if the form has no `action`, the page will still refresh). Your ajax call in the submit handler is done IN ADDITION to the default behavior, not instead of it. You can prevent the default behavior in your submit handler like this:

```
$(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Yeah i had tried that, but when i do, the message is there but the modal box wont fade away

Comment: I can see that your ajax success handler changes text on the screen, but it doesn't contain any code that would remove the modal box. Did you intend to add something like `$('.modal').remove();` to your ajax success handler function?

Comment: hadn't thought of that, which makes perfect sense

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the reason why its refreshing is because you are calling the submit function without preventing the default operation after the line `$(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(){` you need to prevent it:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

If not you can try and prevent the default attached to a clicked event rather than the submit event.

Comment: Also OP, to be clear, you are currently using `return true;` at the end of your submit function. You can simply change that to `return false;` instead.

Comment: Agree with @OhGodWhy Im struggling to see why if he doesn't want the form to refresh/submit he is using a submit button rather than a normal button

Comment: Submit events can be handy because they can be fired in a few different ways. You can click any submit button in a given form, or press the enter key on a focusable form element, etc. Depending on your needs, it may be easier to prevent default submit behavior than to specify a half-dozen handlers that fire your ajax request.

Comment: @RaphaelSerota Ohh, I didnt think of it that way thanks

Answer (score 0):

When using a form with a submit button, the browser will perform a postback anyway. So, I suggest that you replace the input type="submit" with input type="button". And then attach your handler to "click" of that button (instead of the form's submit event). You will also need to read the value of the textarea and put that value in the data to be passed.